# LaTeX Error: Too deeply nested

Tags: nesting

I'm trying to debug a

> Too deeply nested

error in LaTeX. It's not an obvious case of too deeply nested itemize or enumerate items. It's happening far into the document, at a `\begin{quote}`.

Is there a way to get LaTeX to tell which counter(s) are causing the problem?

Comment: Please, show the minimal code reproducing the error.

Comment: The `quote` environment is implemented as a list, if I remember correctly. So this essentially *is* another list and, if nested too deeply, will cause the same error as an explicit `itemize` or `enumerate` would. By the way, [welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) For details of what Sigur is asking, please see this information about producing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.